# Notarizing an app with altool: How to correct "Error: altool encountered an error. No command argument was specified"

Tags: macos

I have a Mac app I wish to notarize. I've signed the app using `codesign` and stored my Apple credentials in a keychain using

`xcrun altool --store-password-in-keychain-item "AC_PASSWORD" -u "my_email.gmail" -p "apple-password"`

(Of course I used my own Apple email/username and PWD above.)

At the Apple developer's site I've also created an explicit bundle ID, "org.gvsu.determinant"

Now I try to put all this together, where determinant_calculator.zip is a compressed copy of my application. At the command line I type

```
xcrun altool —notarize-app -f 
/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/determinants/determinant_calculator.zip --primary-bundle-id 
org.gvsu.determinant -u my_email@gmail.com —password "@keychain:AC_PASSWORD"
```

The resulting error message states "No command argument was specified"

I've never tried to notarize a Mac application before, and I realize I'm missing some very fundamental principles, and/or my question may not be articulated clearly enough. I'm trying to do everything outside Xcode.